# In an ActiveRecord relation with eager loading, how can you pluck the primary column without duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I have an Active Record relation that preloads other model data like this:

```
input = Post.active.includes(:comments)
```

If I try to pluck the primary column I get duplicates:

```
output = input.pluck(:id)
(2.8ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" WHERE "posts"."aasm_state" = 1
=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Sure, I could just rewrite the first expression without 'includes':

```
input = Post.active
output = input.pluck(:id)
```

However, with the library I am using that is not an option (https://github.com/toptal/chewy -> a wrapper for ElasticSearch to help index ActiveRecord data). The first part (input) of the code is used outside of the gem, in the app code, while the last part is in the gem itself:

```
# app/something.rb
input = Post.active.includes(:comments)

# lib/something_else.rb
# target is the model defined in the input
ids = input.pluck("#{target.primary_key}")
```

The "includes" part is important because all the data is bulk imported to ElasticSearch, so eager loading is a must.

Another alternative I've tried is forking the gem and changing the mentioned code to this:

```
ids = input.pluck("distinct(#{target.table_name}.#{target.primary_key})")
```

That does provide the expected result, but it has (at least) two problems:

1. In SQL, 'distinct' should be used carefully, since it interacts with around 'order by' and 'group by';
2. Performance penalty because you are still running the LEFT OUTER JOINS that happen as a consequence of the eager loading part. In fact, this is a **huge issue** for me, which is my primary motivation for writing this post here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you tried appending `.uniq!` to `Post.includes(:comments)` ?

Comment: `input.uniq.pluck(:id)` should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, @Pavan! I hadn't tried it, but I see now that it gives the same result: a SELECT DISTINCT ... (and the LEFT OUTER JOIN remains)

Comment: Hi, @BroiSatse! As with the previous comment, that doesn't remove the SELECT DISTINCT and LEFT OUTER JOIN as I need

Comment: Then how about `input.unscoped.pluck(:id)?`, or more generic (and uglier): `input.dup.tap {|r| r.includes_values = []}.pluck(:id)`

Comment: Nice try, @BroiSatse! The only problem with that is that the gem has to keep the scope (WHERE and INNER JOIN parts) because the data is not always processed all at once. For example, when one comment is added to a post, only the part associated with that is refreshed. I have just updated the question to try to make that clearer.

Comment: The second option will keep all the where values and will not modify the original input relation, so should match the requirements. :)

Comment: Great, @BroiSatse! That's what I was looking for! You can officialize your comment as an answer, so I can accept it formally.

Comment: @DonGiovanni - Answer you posted is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem maintainer posted a cleaner answer [here](https://github.com/toptal/chewy/pull/219#issuecomment-121710706):

```
input.except(:includes).pluck(:id)
```